# Storing data to firebase from android client

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello i'm a newbie on firebase, i'm creating a simple app to store text data on my firebase database. My goal is just to store the text but it seems that i cannot store the text.

I have this code for my send button which gets the value from the textbox and send it to the database. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
public void onSendButtonClick(View v) {
    String message = mMessageEdit.getText().toString();
    Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put("name", "puf");
    values.put("message", message.toString());
    mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(values);
    mMessageEdit.setText("");
}
```

Hope you could help me with this simple newbie problem.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Add a [CompletionListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener) to your `setValue()` to see if it fires and what the returned `DatabaseError` is.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make a long variable to save date in millisecond.

```
long currentTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeInMillis();
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("date", currentTimeInMillis);
mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(values);
```

And then to convert it back I use DateFormat class (from android.text.format)

```
public static String getDate(String dateFormat, long currentTimeInMillis) {
        return DateFormat.format(dateFormat, currentTimeInMillis); }

// Example usage
getDate("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "38232213325");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Map of type `Map<String, Object>` to write your values:

```
public void onSendButtonClick(View v) {
    String message = mMessageEdit.getText().toString();
    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put("name", "puf");
    values.put("message", message);
    mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(values);
    mMessageEdit.setText("");
}
```